# How to get autocomplete address while typing and get coordinates

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, location, maps

I want to show a UI like below
[image]

and when user starts entering keywords I want to populate it with search results which when click on a particular name.
map should get displayed with marker and I want to fetch the lat and long for that marker pointer.

Can I do it for free using google API for web as I am doing it in reactjs
or is there any other good API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with [Google's Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) for the dropdown, you can even narrow the search to a specific country. There's a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-places-autocomplete) I've used that's very nice and relatively straightforward that you can integrate with your dropdown API calls, they have functions that allow for getting lat and long values of data in the dropdown list.

The map is a separate issue; I'd suggest passing your coordinates through your URL or via props to a child component after a user selects the location they want. In your map component (which will need Google Maps API or some other map like Mapbox integrated into the component), you would use these co-ordinates to define a marker (passed from props etc.). I would also suggest using Google API for the maps, as there are npm packages ([discontinued but still works](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps) & a [more recent package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api)) that easily allow for you to plot custom markers as well as multiple markers.

Comment: But googls API is asking for billing account. It isn't free

Comment: Yeah, it's free up to a point. If you stay under [$200 worth of requests per month](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing), it is free. If you go over this limit they need your billing information to be able to charge you. I have been using Google API over three apps that are not huge, and so I'm always under this limit. You'll find most map's aren't 'free' to use, or if they are there's a paywall at some point.

Comment: but in my case its asking for billing information even before using API.

Comment: Apologies I misquoted. Yes, that's correct. they require it outright but won't actually charge you unless you break this request limit. It's kept as sort of an insurance policy of incase your requests surge above the limit they know they are able to charge you. Without this, anyone could make multiple accounts and keep using free Maps with excess of max free requests.